# Change background color by variable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to put the color of the background, according to a variable.

The code is:

```
return <div className="navbar" style={{ background: dataColor }}></div>;
```

This code only works for me when the assignment to the variable is like this:

```
const dataColor = "#120000";
```

And not like this:

```
const dataColor2 = props.children;
```

(props.children comes from somewhere else, and its value is correct. I checked it).

What is the problem?

Thank You!

Comment: "And not like this" – what specifically happens when you use `props.children`? As you say, you verified its value was correct.

Comment: When I try to print this values, with: "return <div className="navbar" style={{ background: props.children }}>dataColor: {dataColor}. <br></br>dataColor2: {dataColor2}</div>;" I get the correct value. but the backgroudColor doesn't work with dataColor2. (it's work only with dataColor)

Comment: console.log(props.children) to see how you are receiving the value. If it's an object, you need to get the value from the key. Perhaps with more details we could better take a look at your issue. For instance we don't know where exactly you are defining those variables, were they defined inside a component? Add more code related to the part where the data is being passed as well. Maybe you shouldn't define a variable that way, use state: const [data, setData]  = useState(props.children) that way you are setting the initial value correctly

Answer (score 0):

I would say the value is set to late. Try to use an await.

Comment: I dont think so. beacuse when I tried to do: 
: "return <div className="navbar" style={{ background: props.children }}>dataColor: {dataColor}. <br></br>dataColor2: {dataColor2}</div>;" 
I get the correct value. but the backgroudColor doesn't work with dataColor2. (it's work only with dataColor). so I don't think that it's depend in time / set to late.